# SQL Server I can see stored procedure with VBA in Excel but user group cannot

Tags: sql-server, vba, stored-procedures, ssms

I created a stored procedure and can execute it with the VBA below.  I gave a user group (of which I am a member) Execute permission.  All members of that group except me get the error 'could not find stored procedure' when running the VBA.  The users can log in through SSMS and execute the stored procedure by right clicking it.

When I look at the Effective tab where I granted Execute permissions there is an error: Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "MyUserGroup" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

The SQL admin told me that my group does have DBO level permissions.  What am I missing?  Why can't they find the stored procedure when they execute the Excel VBA?  Or is that error telling me that I cannot grant them permission when I should be able to?

Excel VBA to call stored procedure:

```
Function Sproc()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrSproc As String

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=ThisDatabase;Data Source=ThisSource;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=ThisSourceID;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    StrSproc = "ExportListToExcel"
    rst.ActiveConnection = cnn
    rst.Open StrSproc

    For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rst.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst
Exit Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> StrSproc = "ExportListToExcel"

Name resolution is the first thing rule out.

The name, without schema-qualification will be resolved first in the user's default schema, and then in `dbo` schema.

So schema-qualify the procedure name to be sure.

Comment: Happy New Year David Browne!  Thank you!